# Undesired shutdown on low battery - Debian Testing

Tags: linux, debian, battery

I'm currently using Debian Testing (stretch) after a hard drive crash on my laptop, but I'm facing a weird issue with it. The laptop (Acer 5830TG) has a non-removable three-cell 6000mAh Li-Ion battery, current capacity only 335mAh due to wear, which does not permit charging until battery voltage drops below 10.9 V. Previously the laptop had Debian Testing Jessie, Fedora 21 and Slax Live, but none of those shut down automatically on low battery (even voltage below 10.8 V). The latest Debian is shutting down if the battery level is below 10%, and currently I'm facing frequent short term power cuts.

**So what is wrong with that?**

- Some power saving `udev/systemd/dbus` rules?
- Any kind of new kernel feature to avoid battery over-discharge?
- Or system misconfiguration?

**Points to note**

- I got battery voltage/capacity, etc., from `/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0`
- not any kind of hardware issue;
  tested with Slax, Lubuntu, Tiny Core live USB
- not any kind of desktop or display manager issue; I do not use any display manager and logout X session when no AC power.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem solved by myself, its UPower daemon, which is automatically started by dbus-daemon, as soon as I start any X session it starts automatically, but closing X session does not stop upower daemon. So logout X session and run

sudo service upower stop

and problem solved.

Comment: Take a look at `/etc/UPower/UPower.conf`. There is what UPower should do when battery is too low (`CriticalPowerAction`). And yes, it is really stupid default settings.